# uGUIでSetParent(null)を使ってはいけない？

Tags: unity3d, ugui

uGUIでSetParent(null)を使ってはいけないのでしょうか？

Unity4.6から、TransformにSetParentというメソッドができて、parent=としていた記述は、「SetParentを使うように」というwarningがでていると思います。

warningにしたがってコードを修正したのですが、parent=null;　としていたのを　SetParent(null)とすると、潜在的に不具合を抱えたままゲームが進行して何かのきっかけでバグるようです。自分のアプリではほぼ再現率100%でUnityエディタがクラッシュする手順があります。ただ似たようなロジックのところでは正常に動作するため、どういう要素が影響しているかまではわかりませんでした。

SetParent(null)を使用していたのは、子オブジェクトを全部削除するときで、このように書いていました。

```
 //SetParent(null)の書き方だとどうもマズイ模様
 while (parent.childCount > 0)
 {
      Transform child = parent.GetChild(0);
      child.SetParent(null);
      GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
 }
```

このように変えたら直りました。

```
 //書き方を変更
 foreach(Transform t in this.transform)
 {
      Destroy(t.gameObject);
 }
```

SetParent(null)としていたのは、削除したときに、parent.childCountもちゃんとゼロになるようにしたかったからです。
GameObject.Destroyだけでは、1フレーム後じゃないと子オブジェクトが削除されないらしく、明示的にparent=nullとすることで子オブジェクトから外れるようにしていたのですが、.SetParent(null)とした場合は不正な処理になるようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

直前にSetActive(false)とすることで動作するようになりました。
おそらくですが、uGUIのオブジェクトはCanvas以下に置かれる前提で設計されているため、SetParent(null)としてルート直下にあるオブジェトにすると不具合を起こすのだと思います。

```
   //SetActive(false);とすると動く
   while (parent.childCount > 0)
   {
        Transform child = parent.GetChild(0);
        child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        child.SetParent(null);
        GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
   }
```